# Grails filters with static resources?

Tags: grails, filter

I'm converting an old school Java filter to a Grails filter. (The filter is recording access to particular static image.)

The problem is, I can't get it fire! **Does Grails support filters in front of static resources?**

```
class EmailImageFilters {
    def filters = {
        emailFilter(uri: '/images/**') {
            log.info "email filter ${new Date()}"
            before = {
                return true;
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

I am using the UIPerformance plugin, but it's not turned on in development mode.

Grails 1.3.5

I can get it to fire when:

```
emailFilter(controller: '*', action: '*') {
```

but I need it to be through static resources; e.g. /images

Suggestions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Static resources aren't served by a controller, so Grails filters (which are wrappers for Spring controller interceptors) won't fire for requests for them. You need to register a servlet filter in web.xml to process static resources.

Create a class in src/java or src/groovy that implements `javax.servlet.Filter`, then run `grails install-templates` and edit `src/templates/war/web.xml` to register it, something like

```
<filter>
   <filter-name>myFilter</filter-name>
   <filter-class>com.mycompany.myapp.MyFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>myFilter</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Change the value of url-pattern to be more specific if you don't want it to fire for all requests.

Comment: Thanks Burt.  That's what I have now in src/groovy and updated web.xml.  But I don't believe I have access to an injected log, dataSource and GORM objects in this filter.  That's why I wanted to migrate to a Grails filter.

Comment: There's no auto-injected logger, but you can get one the usual way, i.e. Logger.getLogger(getClass()). You can get access to Spring beans like dataSource via ApplicationHolder.application.mainContext.dataSource. And GORM methods should work if you call from Groovy, although you probably need to wrap in a withTransaction block to avoid lazy loading exceptions since you won't be within the scope of the OpenSessionInViewInterceptor.