# Grails filter url pattern

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

I need to cache static resources in grails using custom filter.

I used below post:

[Grails filters with static resources?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5668190/grails-filters-with-static-resources/5669260#5669260)

However, the filter is not getting invoked for static resources and gets hit on controller url's only.

I tried different patterns:

```
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
                      (or)
    <url-pattern>*.img</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
```

Am i missing something? I am using grails 2.1.1

Please suggest.

Comment: Are you using the resources plugin?